# unit test of arbitrary function on a remote embedded mcu using function pointers and variable arguments of arbitrary type, in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

the idea is to write ONE universal unit test function that would execute arbitrary function-under-test on the embedded target mcu side using an externally generated test input arguments (from communication for example). so that the unit test function for the remote mcu is written only once and the test cases are generated on a host PC by sending the known function address and input arguments through some communication means.

for example, if on a remote mcu there is a function of
int sumoftwoints(int, int) to be tested, the host pc would pass to this unitTestFcn pointer the address of sumoftwoints (known by linker) and two random ints generated on the host pc then send to the embedded target by uart. the embedded target "calls" by the function pointer received with the supplied number of argument and returns the result to send back to the host pc for result check.

any feedback on if this is plausible or there is fundamental flaw in this test scheme?

the benefit is to move the unit test from the embedded side to the host pc side, which has infinite test case expandability.

Comment: Any scheme relying on assumptions of how the program was compiled and linked, and then using these assumptions to access the program parts which are not supposed to be accessed by intended means is flawed. If you want a testing interface in your program - program it separately, with dedicated protocol and "business logic".

Comment: Are you saying that the program on the embedded MCU is written in C?

Comment: This is probably not a great idea, since the PC might have different data sizes, endianess and so on. Just write the tests for the target MCU and execute them on the target MCU. I just don't understand this nearly fanatic obsession of PCs that all test engineers seem to got. What if the target MCU has a silicon bug or instruction trap which only manifests itself if you run the test on the intended target? Tests are there to increase the quality of the product, not to keep the tester happy because they get to run their favourite bloated PC test suite.

Comment: @Lundin, in my context the target mcu is of size of 32k or 64k flash size. it is impractical to write comprehensive test cases and 'run' them on the same target.

Comment: @TRPh, yes they are written in C. let's say an STM32F M0 processor with small flash footprint. but the purpose is to test out the compiled image, so it does not restrain what language it was written in (assembly or cpp).

Comment: @EugeneSh. that is exactly the point of testing it that way so to test only the function on the target but to feed the test case inputs from an external source. i can write infinite test cases on the pc with previously untested cases. another important thing is to run the test WITHOUT having to recompile the code. this can be a scenario where the embedded code is already on a released product. it might have caused by a corrupted flash or reasons that a recompilation may mask the issue.

Comment: @lgz 32kb is oceans of memory. Simply test one module/one requirement at a time, which you probably ought to be doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to make a system like this, I'd make it consist of 3 parts:

- The PC-side software where you specify your tests in the form of a function address and arguments.
- A receiver/transmitter pair that implements some kind of communication between PC and MCU, e.g. over serial, Wifi or whatever's available.
- A test executor that runs on the MCU, that executes the function, and returns the result, if any.

Tbe PC-side software could read some artifacts produced by your build process to simplify things, e.g. so you may use actual function names instead of having to specify the actual address in your tests.

The communication protocol should be text based, relying on the receiver to convert values as appropriate for the receiving platform.

The executor would have to implement the ABI specific to the architecture of the MCU. This is where you'll reach your first major hurdle. First of all, ABIs vary a lot. From Arm where some arguments are passed in one or more registers, some as pointers to the actual argument, and some on stack, to x86 where it's all stack based.

Your next major hurdle is going to be structs. If you're going to allow functions with struct parameters or return values to be called, you have to know how your compiler chose to pack the fields for each specific struct.

All in all, creating something like this would be a non-trivial undertaking, and probably ending up being not that useful, unless you put a *lot* of work into it, as in making it a commercial product.

Another alternative is that you leave some scratch space on the device, then crosscompile your tests on the PC, then send them over to the MCU one by one or in groups, to be installed in the scratch space and be executed.

In any case, this kind of functionality should never be included in a shipping product, due to obvious security concerns.